# Function in R which gives custom colour (from a given interval) to the borders of a continuous data plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale, continuous

The function supposed to use colours from the give scale (between low and high) for the border colours if I plot continuous data plot using ggplot2.

```
> scale_colour_continuous <- function(...) {  
> ggplot2::scale_colour_gradient(..., low = "#FFFF00", high = "#3366FF",
>                                na.value = "#262626", aesthetics = "colour")
```

Unfortunately, my code above doesn't appear to be working. I find if very interesting, because the same thing for the the fills of the plot works fine with the same arguments (`aesthetics = "fill"`). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly call `ggplot2`. If you want to,you could add an if statement that checks if ggplot2 is loaded. This works as required.

```
my_theme<-function(...){
  scale_colour_gradient(..., low = "#FFFF00", high = "#3366FF",
            na.value = "#262626", aesthetics = "colour")

}
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length,col=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  my_theme()#wanted to make a theme so don't mind the naming.
```